# How to get list of shared folder and remove the desired folder from being shared using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am using this command to get the list of shared folder:

```
net view "hostname" /all
```

I am replacing the hostname with my computer name. I am just able to get the list of shared folder, but how do I remove it using a batch file.

What I am really trying to do is create a batch file which scans the shared folder and removes all of it. With no user input.

The host name can be captured by running hostname command and replacing it in the actual script.  Like this, but how do I get the file path and remove the sharing from it.

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i

net view %MYVAR% /all
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

I tried this:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i

for /F %%a IN ('wmic /node:"%MYVAR%" share get path^|findstr "\<E:\>"') DO (
echo %%a
NET SHARE %%a /DELETE
)

endlocal
```

But the problem is I just need to find the correct regex for drive letter. Can you please suggest some correct regex which can identify correct drive letter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `%computername%` variable instead of using a `for /f` loop

```
net view %computername% /all
```

And then to delete a share, use

```
net share %computername% /delete
```

Comment: I have updated an answer above, the net view wont work as it does not have the folder path or it does not allow to select what to delete.